# Spreadsheet - I want to append data from one sheet to another, they only have one column that can be used as a reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have two sheets that only have one column in common - **ID** column.

I'd like to compare those two columns and if id's match, to append data into Sheet 1 from the matching row.

I don't know if I'm clear enough so here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Sheets append data]

I've tried looking for any solution, but it's a bit too specific.

Hopefully someone here can explain how can I achieve this?

Comment: What will be for duplicate data like ID `1003`. Do you want both records or only one record?

Comment: `INDEX()+MATCH()` or `VLookup()` is enough for you I think.

Comment: I've tried with VLookup() but I just don't understand how that should work, I'll give a go with INDEX()+MATCH() and see what I can find. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an **one formula** solution then use this in cell **D2** of **Sheet1**:

```
=arrayformula({iferror(vlookup(A2:A, {Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!B2:B},2,false),""),iferror(vlookup(A2:A, {Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!C2:C},2,false),""),
iferror(vlookup(A2:A, {Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!D2:D},2,false),""),iferror(vlookup(A2:A, {Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet2!E2:E},2,false),"")
})
```

[image: output]

---

A **better** alternative suggested by [marikamitsos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527780/marikamitsos) is this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2!A2:E,{2,3,4,5})))
```

Comment: Actually you can use the simpler formula: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet2!A2:E,{2,3,4,5})))`

Comment: We actually turn the outcome to an array using `{2,3,4,5}`. Glad I could help.

Comment: @marikamitsos I learn a lot of things from you. Thanks :)

Comment: @Marios Please feel free -if you want to- to edit your answer using the new formula. Many people don't make it to the comments.

Comment: @marikamitsos I did :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

If you want `Vlookup()` then use-

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$E,COLUMN(B$1))
```